# How to use mobx-react-devtools

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I've installed `mobx-react-devtools` as a dev dependency, imported its reference in my `index.js`, and inserted `<DevTools />` as instructed in the npm docs.

However I get 3 errrors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
TypeError: (0 , a.trackComponents) is not a function
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { observable, configure } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import DevTools from 'mobx-react-devtools';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
configure({ enforceActions: 'observed' }); // All state that is observed somewhere needs to be changed through actions

const appState = observable({
  count: 0,
  incCount: () => {
    appState.count += 1;
  },
  decCount: () => {
    appState.count -= 1;
  },
});

const Counter = observer((props) => (
  <section>
    {props.appState.count}
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.appState.incCount}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={props.appState.decCount}>Dec</button>
      <DevTools />
    </div>
  </section>
));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Counter appState={appState} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-mobx-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.3.0",
    "mobx": "^6.0.4",
    "mobx-react": "^7.0.5",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^6.1.1"
  }
}
```

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/react-mobx-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the makers of the [mobx-react-devtools](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-devtools) team

Note: This package is deprecated. Use the [browser plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobx-developer-tools/pfgnfdagidkfgccljigdamigbcnndkod) instead. Also note that with mobx-react@6 and higher the package should no longer be needed, see changelog

Comment: The tool has been DEPRECATED